# QGIS - creating a report from attribute table

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, grouping, reports

I create a report from attribute table. At one column I have a name of a street, at second column I have a number. Relation between street and a number is one-to-many. Is there a function to show at the report table name of a street only for biggest number or alternativelly group the column with name of a street the same way it is possible in MS excel, as shown at the picture below?

[image]

Comment: I need to use a function, because I create a report. Also, I need to be able to update a table simply.

Comment: Please, correct me if I understand you question the wrong way, but you can try the [`maximum()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#maximum) i.e. `maximum("number", group_by:="Street")` and the [`sum()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#sum) i.e. `sum("number", group_by:="Street")` functions

Answer (score 1):

Use this expression:

```
if (
    maximum( number,"street" )=
    attribute( get_feature_by_id (@layer, $id), 'number'),
    street,
    ''
)
```

*Screenshot: I used the same values as in your screenshot, see the result:*
[image]

Comment: Thank you. I have "NULL" in some street fields. What is incorrect on function if("street" IS NULL, ' ',(if (
    maximum( number,"street" )=
    attribute( get_feature_by_id (@layer, $id), 'number'),
    street,
    ''
))?

Comment: You have simply forgot one closing bracket `)` at the end.  If you have a `NULL` value, result will be `NULL` as well

Comment: But you don't need any special if-clause for `NULL`, the expression from my solution works well even for `NULL` values.